# Google Analytics for desktop app after the Firebase change

Tags: google-analytics, desktop-application

I used to be able to create an Application property in google analytics and then use Measurement Protocol to send hits from a desktop app.

Now, it seems that google only allow you to create a property for a website, or for a mobile app through Firebase Analytics. Firebase, however, does not seem to support measurement app, and I couldn't find any other HTTP API or anything else that can be used from a desktop. The only way I could find to send analytics to firebase was through their mobile SDK, which I can't use on desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: what prevents you from creating your app as website in Google (Firebase) Analytics ?

Comment: would it work int that case?